# How can i use FileSystemWatcher created not change

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

i have some questions about FileSystemWatcher of C#.

Here is my code as below.

```
    private void MyFileSystemWatcher()
    {
        _watch = new FileSystemWatcher(path);
        _watch.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.Size;
        _watch.Filter = "*.*";
        _watch.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

        _watch.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(_watch_Changed);
        _watch.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(_watch_Created);

        _watch.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void _watch_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File changed: {0}", e.Name);
    }

    private void _watch_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File created: {0}", e.Name);
    }
```

When I drop book.txt to directory, it is my result.

```
File created: book.txt
File changed: book.txt
```

But It's not the result I expected. I hope it just trigger off the created event.

```
File created: book.txt
```

How can I improve my code. I can't remove the changed event, I have use of the other case.

Comment: Side note: sometimes you really get unexpected sequences of notifications due to the way operations on files are implemented... After properly listening on file changes you should try other operations - saving, copy in different ways, copy-paste/drag'n'drop and make sure you handle all cases sensibly.

Comment: Are you moving a file or creating a copy? In any case, note that file attributes may be updated as a result of moving or copying a file, hence the "changed" event. `FileSystemWatcher` is simply doing what you asked it to do. If you don't want to react to a particular changed event, then don't. What is it you're actually having trouble with here? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I need the changed event to monitor content of file has been modified or not. And I need the created event to monitor a new file, not trigger off the changed event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Changed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed(v=vs.110).aspx) event says:

> The Changed event is raised when **changes are made to the size**, system attributes, last write time, last access time, or security permissions of a file **or directory** in the directory being monitored.

You monitor folder and by adding a new file to it you change its size, so you get notified by event.

So naturally, when you move files back and forth on file system you might get a sequence of different events. You just need to read the property you get from event and act accordingly.

Comment: I don't believe this answer addresses the question. The change event they are asking about is in fact for the _file_, not the directory. Other issues with your answer include the fact that a directory doesn't actually have a size (so a change in size couldn't possibly be what triggers notification), and that your answer _doesn't actually solve the OP's problem, whatever that might be_.

Answer (score 1):

```
private bool isOnCreated = false;

.....

private void _watch_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if(isOnCreated)
       isOnCreated  = false;
    else
       Console.WriteLine("File changed: {0}", e.Name);
}

private void _watch_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("File created: {0}", e.Name);
    isOnCreated  = true;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue just now, and this page was one of the first search results - I know it's an older question but as there's not a conclusive answer I'll be presumptuous and add my solution.
The specific behavior that I saw was that upon creating a file, both the **Change** and **Create** events were fired by the FileSystemWatcher.

e.g. if from a command prompt I typed:

```
echo test >foobar.txt
```

..then my FSW fired for **Change** of foobar.txt, then **Creation** of the file. Whilst technically correct, as explained by Tigran above, I'm really only interested in presenting the Create event to the user.

My solution was trivial. I created a boolean flag to indicate whether the FSW event handler had fired, and set that to TRUE when the Create event occurred. I modified the Change event handler to only take action if the flag was set to false.
In other words, only one event gets processed each cycle (in my case, when the user clicks a button to acknowledge the event, the flag gets reset) and priority is given to the Create event.

I hope this helps others who've encountered the same challenge.